# call method from an included class when a method with same name is defined in the class

Tags: ruby

I have the following code - (from rubymonks)

```
module Foo
  class ClassMethods
    def guitar
      "gently weeps"
    end
  end
end

class Bar
  include Foo
  def self.guitar
    puts "hehe"
    #call guitar function from ClassMethods
  end
end

puts Bar.guitar
```

Here, how do I call the guitar function from ClassMethods. ClassMethods is not a super class, so can't use super keyword.

Comment: Despite the name, RubyMonk exercises seem to cause more confusion than clarity.

Comment: i don't know whyyyyyyyyy nobody told me.

Comment: Just replace that line with `ClassMethods.new.guitar`. It will print "hehe" on one line followed by "gently weeps" on the next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That kind of structure is usually used to both, *include* and *extend* a Module with a single call to `include`. It works by setting up an [`included`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Module.html#method-i-included) callback that invokes the [`extend`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Object.html#method-i-extend) call:

```
module Foo
  def self.included(mod)
    mod.extend(ClassMethods)
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def guitar
      "gently weeps"
    end
  end
end

class Bar
  include Foo

  def self.guitar
    puts "hehe"
    super
  end
end

puts Bar.guitar
#=> hehe
#=> gently weeps
```

The above is equivalent to:

```
module Foo
  module ClassMethods
    def guitar
      "gently weeps"
    end
  end
end

class Bar
  include Foo
  extend Foo::ClassMethods

  def self.guitar
    puts "hehe"
    super
  end
end
```

Of course, `include Foo` only makes sense if there are instance methods (or constants / module variables). In your example, you only need `extend`.